# Is there a way to reliably checkpoint a JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, checkpoint

I'm looking for a way to reliably checkpoint a JVM so that partial results in a large-scale computation by a Java program can be saved and the computation can be restarted where it left off next time the JVM is started. I searched for solutions online, but the results mostly come from research works which are not mature industrial solutions. Is there a way, as in the year of 2018, to reliably checkpoint a JVM that I'm not aware of?

If the answer is yes, could you please provide a link? If the answer is no, another approach I can think of is to run the Java program inside a system virtual machine and checkpoint that instead. I haven't tested it. But I'm wondering why such checkpoint is not possible on a process virtual machine like JVM.

Comment: A JVM is pretty complex, so this would be a nontrivial undertaking.  You might have luck making your computation classes serializable, if they retain the progress and state of the computation in instance variables.

Comment: You need to serialize the state you need to recover. Many classes are not serializable and cannot be checkpointed e.g. Threads, Sockets, File handles, GUI components,